# VS2017 Live visual tree auto selection does not work

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

When I run my WPF application, I can't explore window's visual tree, using "Enable selection" feature. This button has no effect.
Tried on different PC's with the same behaviour, so the problem is related only to this app, not to VS instance.

How this feature works? May it be overriden with some code?
Any ideas where to search?
(App uses Devexpress and Prism)

Edit: I know about the 3rd party tools, that allow to explore visual tree, but I am wondering why this VS feature does not work in this particular app?

Comment: In "Live Visual Tree" window you have to toggle "Enable selection in the running application" (the shortcut button in runtime tools does it), then switch to application and move mouse around to see red rectangle around currently mouse-overed element, clicking on it will select it in the "Live Visual Tree". It would be nice if you explain carefully procedure, what you expect and what doesn't work.

Comment: Other tools for looking at the Visual Tree are Inspect and VisualUIAVerify, from the windows SDK

Comment: Should work pretty much like snoop - here https://github.com/cplotts/snoopwpf you can look at the source code...

Comment: I know about the 3rd party tools, but I am wondering why this particular VS feature does not work in this particular app?